# Invalid procedure or function reference - Pascal

Tags: pascal

Could someone tell me why my code throws:

> **Error:** Invalid procedure or function reference - Pascal

```
PROGRAM ITVS_19_1;
TYPE FUNC = FUNCTION(x:REAL):REAL;
VAR a, b, k1, k2:REAL;

FUNCTION f(x:REAL):REAL;
BEGIN
  f:=SQR(COS(x))-2/35*COS(x)-1/35;
END;

FUNCTION g(x:REAL):REAL;
BEGIN
  g:=SQR(COS(x))-2/5*COS(x)-1/25;
END;

FUNCTION PYB(f:FUNC; a, b, C:REAL):REAL;
BEGIN
  WHILE ABS(F(a) - F(b)) > 0.00001 DO
  BEGIN
    c:=(a+b)/2;
    IF (f(a)*f(c)) < 0 THEN
      b:=c
    ELSE
      a:=c;
  END;
  PYB:=(a+b)/2;
END;
 
BEGIN
  READ(a, b);
  k1:=PYB(f, a, b);
  k2:=PYB(f, a, b);
  WRITELN('f-funksiya', k1);
  WRITELN('g-funksiya', k2);
END.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `PYB` is declared:

```
FUNCTION PYB(f:FUNC; a, b, C:REAL):REAL;
```

The call to this procedure requires three `REAL` parameters, while you only pass two:

```
k1:=PYB(f, a, b);
```